# Стилизация форума на PHPBB3

Tags: phpbb, php, вёрстка

Сейчас у меня вот такая ерунда: http://joxi.ru/AxYvOyN Вопросы:

1. Как сделать чтобы картинка не дублировалась?
2. Как сделать чтобы высота шапки была четко ограничена?

Оговорюсь сразу, нужно подогнать это: http://joxi.ru/MbDDuyy вот под это: http://joxi.ru/ASsMro5

Кто чем сможет помочь? Добился этого: http://joxi.ru/GEDtRiD Вопросы:

1. Как вернуть качество.
2. Как сделать окантовку вокруг шапки как на рисунке?

http://moemesto.ru/NarMax/file/14336484/2012-09-24_141603.JPG

Comment: Это скорей не работа, а опыт. Я новичок и набираюсь опыта. 
В интернете, к сожалению, информации не нашел, пришел сюда. 
А захламлять комментарии не хочется.
По поиску(bg_header.gif) ничего не нашел.

Comment: Если вы учитесь верстке, то это наидурнейший способ, который можно было придумать. Верстайте аккуратные макеты с нуля, для начала, пока не будите себя уверенно чувствовать.

Comment: Я приму Ваш совет, но очень прошу, помогите мне решить эту проблему.

Comment: А вы пробовали с самого начала просто подменить файл http://ruseo.net/styles/prosilver/imageset/site_logo.gif на то, что вам надо. Это во-первых. Во-вторых, разве в самом форуме у администратора нет настроек на загрузку нового логотипа через админку или что-нибудь в этом духе?

Comment: Есть. Изображение там выбрано.
http://joxi.ru/Z5Advnn

Comment: Знаит возвращайтесь к верстке. Ищите в firebug тег, в котором все эти логотипы появились. В нем и в его свойствах ответ. Так больше ничего не скажешь, кроме того, что нужно попробовать убрать background-repeat или посмотреть, может ли другие теги пораждают логотипы. Выкладывайте скиншот того, что вы видите когда выделяете в firebug`е этот тег.

Comment: А что если попробовать по другому?<br>
Место bg_header.gif поставить site_logo.gif.<br>
Тогда выходит так:http://joxi.ru/OpmEz4<br>
Вроде бы ничего, но надо изменить размер самой картинки. Через css на что ссылаться?

Comment: Сначала попробовать просто увеличить картинку. Если не поможет, то искать тэг с этой картинкой. Если она задается тегом img - то ее размеры можно устанавливать при помощи css-свойств width и height. Если она задается как background, то ее размеры можно задавать при помощи css-свойства background-size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все через CSS. При помощи инструмента Firebug (firefox - плагин, chrome - встроенный) ищите нужный селектор и добавляйте свойства:

```
 1. background-repeat: no-repeat;
 2. height: 200px;
```

Comment: no-repeat стоит, но дублируется. может потому что я в Z:\home\test1.ru\www\styles\prosilver\theme\images файл bg_header.gif использовал как шапку?

Как убрать вот такую штукенцию? http://joxi.ru/GM0Gcwc

Чтобы не отвечать на кучу моих вопросов, можете сказать как преобразовать это: http://joxi.ru/MbDDuyy, в это: http://joxi.ru/ASsMro5

Comment: Ссылка на картинку, что вы дает - ссылка на локальный файл вашего компьютера. В любом случае, какая бы там картинка не стояла фоном, она повторяется. Снимается это свойство, как я указал в ответе. Попробуйте добавить !important, чтобы получилось вот так: **background-repeat: no-repeat !important;**

Comment: http://joxi.ru/11IXXNU
Сделал как Вы сказали. Как видите, все осталось на месте.

Comment: Ну в рамках одного dl оно должно работать, да. Смотрите firebug`ом, какой код пораждает другие картинки.

Comment: Штукенцую вызвало либо свойство border-radius у какого-то из блоков (ищите firebug`ом), либо вырезанная картинка-уголок (поройтесь в папках с картинками, может так проще будет найти).

Comment: Вы можете мне помочь сделать верстку в пределах форума?

Comment: Штукенцию убрал. Дублирование -- нет.

Comment: В данном случае могу помочь советами или наводками. Работка все же ваша :). По поводу проблемы - возьмите имя картинки и поищите в firebuge. Может это не замощение, а другие части кода генерируют эти картинки.